# Effect of integral domain structure on the additive group of the ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, finite-groups

I was wondering about the implications of the following statement:
The characteristic of an integral domain $R$ must be zero or prime $p$.

This implies that all elements in $R\backslash\{0\}$ should have order $p$ in the commutative group $R,+$. So imposing the ring structure without zero divisors on a commutative group $R,+$ might result in a drastic change of the group structure, because suddenly all the elements are of the same order $p$? How can this be understood intuitively?

Comment: I rewrote your title to be a little more transparent. "ID" is not really a standard abbreviation that people are going to pick up on until they read the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "imposing a ring structure" on $\langle R,+\rangle$ I take that you mean that first one has an abelian group $\langle A,+,-,0\rangle$ and then one considers a distributive product $*:A\times A\to A$.  If $R=\langle A,*,+,-,0\rangle$ satsifies the axiom of a ring then you might say you have "imposed" a ring structure on $A$.

In that case your question could be formalized as: what conditions on $A$ permit the construction of a ring $R$ that is an integral domain of characteristic $p$?

The answer as you noted is $A\cong \bigoplus_{i\in I} \mathbb{Z}_p$ (subject to axiom of choice).  In particular $A$ is a vector spaces.

In fact that would be the natural proof.  Suppose $R$ is a ring of characteristic $p$.  Then the subring $C=\{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$ acts on $R$.  But $C$ is a field.  So $R$ is a $C$-vector space.  Then, under the axiom of choice this vector space has a basis and so $R\cong \bigoplus_{i\in I} \mathbb{Z}/p$.

(Edited to include @Max's valid point.  When a basis is infinite we still mean linear combinations to be finite support; hence, I should not have written $\prod$.)

Comment: +1 I was just about to make the comment in the last paragraph. That's pretty much the heart of it: being a vector space over a field of prime order makes the additive structure "as discrete as possible."

Comment: It should be a direct sum rather than a product, with one distinguished $\mathbb Z/p$ as the "unit and its multiples"